# Flush Mode hibernate utility

Tags: java, hibernate

I try to understand the difference between different hibernate FlushMode. For this, I created a small example of insertion.

```
    session.beginTransaction();
    session.setFlushMode(FlushMode.AUTO);// I tried ALWAYS AND MANUAL
    for (int i = 1; i < 4; i++) {
        Stock stock = new Stock();
        stock.setStockId(i);
        stock.setStockCode("code-"+i);
        stock.setStockName("name-"+i);

        session.save(stock);
        System.out.println("entity saved");
    }

    session.getTransaction().commit();
```

The problem I always have the same behavior as if the flushMode is set to COMMIT.

```
entity saved
entity saved
entity saved
insert into stock (STOCK_CODE, STOCK_NAME, STOCK_ID) values (?, ?, ?)
insert into stock (STOCK_CODE, STOCK_NAME, STOCK_ID) values (?, ?, ?)
insert into stock (STOCK_CODE, STOCK_NAME, STOCK_ID) values (?, ?, ?)
```

while I was expecting to have

```
entity saved
insert into stock (STOCK_CODE, STOCK_NAME, STOCK_ID) values (?, ?, ?)
entity saved
insert into stock (STOCK_CODE, STOCK_NAME, STOCK_ID) values (?, ?, ?)
entity saved
insert into stock (STOCK_CODE, STOCK_NAME, STOCK_ID) values (?, ?, ?)
```

Anyone have an explanation why I have always the same result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I found, after several test, is that session does not happen before every query beacause the purpose of the Hibernate session is to minimise the number of writes to the database, so it will avoid flushing to the database if it thinks that it isn’t needed even explicitly calling session.flush(). This is confirmed in org.hibernate.Session docs

> Except when you explicitly flush(), there are absolutely no guarantees about when the Session executes the JDBC calls, only the order in which they are executed. However, Hibernate does guarantee that the Query.list(..) will never return stale or incorrect data.

Finally to see the difference between the flush modes, do not act on a single entity because hibernate thinks that it will not be useful to flush. So I added a Query in my loop to force Hibernate to flush.
The code below does not flush although the mode used is ALWAYS

```
session.beginTransaction();
session.setFlushMode(FlushMode.ALWAYS );
for (int i = 1; i < 4; i++) {
    Stock stock = new Stock();
    stock.setStockId(i);
    stock.setStockCode("code-"+i);
    stock.setStockName("name-"+i);
    session.save(stock);
    System.out.println("entity saved");
}
session.getTransaction().commit();
```

output :

```
entity saved
entity saved
entity saved
insert into stock (STOCK_CODE, STOCK_NAME, STOCK_ID) values (?, ?, ?)
insert into stock (STOCK_CODE, STOCK_NAME, STOCK_ID) values (?, ?, ?)
insert into stock (STOCK_CODE, STOCK_NAME, STOCK_ID) values (?, ?, ?)
```

Now, if I add after the `System.out.println("entity saved");`

```
Query query = session.createQuery("from StockDailyRecord");
query.list();
```

The output will be :

```
entity saved
insert into stock (STOCK_CODE, STOCK_NAME, STOCK_ID) values (?, ?, ?)
select stockdaily0_.STOCK_REC_ID as STOCK_RE1_1_ from stock_daily_record stockdaily0_
entity saved
insert into stock (STOCK_CODE, STOCK_NAME, STOCK_ID) values (?, ?, ?)
select stockdaily0_.STOCK_REC_ID as STOCK_RE1_1_ from stock_daily_record stockdaily0_
entity saved
insert into stock (STOCK_CODE, STOCK_NAME, STOCK_ID) values (?, ?, ?)
select stockdaily0_.STOCK_REC_ID as STOCK_RE1_1_ from stock_daily_record stockdaily0_
```

Answer (score 1):

Docs for `FlushMode.COMMIT`:
The Session is flushed when Transaction#commit is called.

If you commit the transaction inside of the loop, the result should be the one you are expecting.

regards
slowy

Comment: I don't need to have a specific result, I just want to see the difference between the flush mode. The behavior of the flush mode commit is obvious.

Answer (score 1):

FlushMode.AUTO means that the session will be flushed if you issue a query where inserted or updated entities must be flushed in order for the database to privide the correct answer. From the documentation

> Auto: The Session is sometimes flushed before query execution in order to
>   ensure that queries never return stale state

Hibernate will not immediately flush new entities until it actually needs to. (Unless you are using a stateless-session). If you for some reason need this to happen, you need to perform a flush on the session manually.

Comment: When hibernate needs to make a flush?

Answer (score 0):

```
for session.setFlush(FlushMode.COMMIT);

The Session is flushed when Transaction.commit() is called.
you can get your expected result by committing transaction inside for loop.
But every time you need to begin new transaction because existing will be closed when Transaction.commit() will be called.
```

Comment: I don't need to have a specific result, I just want to see the difference between the flush mode. The behavior of the flush mode commit is obvious.